# how to keep retrieved data from parse.com, but outside of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{}?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a question about `PFQuery` with parse iOS SDK.

I have a several `geoPoints` data in parse with className `SpotList`. Inside of it, there is two column, i.e. `SpotName` and `SpotLocation`.

After retrieve the data, I tried to print it with `println(self.SpotNames)` it in four different locations (see comment in code below).

My question is, why I got an empty array `[]` if I do `println` in location 4? Meanwhile, I can get the whole data by doing `println` in location 1, 2, and 3. Also, is there any method to get the whole data in location 4?

thank you for your help!

```
var SpotNames              = [String]()
var SpotGeoPoints          = [PFGeoPoint]()
var SpotLocationLatitudes  = [CLLocationDegrees]()
var SpotLocationLongitudes = [CLLocationDegrees]()
var SpotLocations          = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "SpotList")
    query.orderByAscending("SpotName")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects:[AnyObject]! , error:NSError!)-> Void in
        if !(error != nil){
            for object in objects!   {
                self.SpotNames.append(object["SpotName"] as String)
                self.SpotGeoPoints.append(object["SpotLocation"] as PFGeoPoint)
                self.SpotLocationLatitudes.append(self.SpotGeoPoints.last?.latitude as CLLocationDegrees!)
                self.SpotLocationLongitudes.append(self.SpotGeoPoints.last?.longitude as CLLocationDegrees!)
                // location 1
            }
            // location 2
        }
        // location 3
    }
    // location 4
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous method, it returns immediately.
So, when you reach location 4, you probably will get an empty array. If you really want to get the result right there, use synchronous version `findObjects`, but doing a heavy work on main thread is always not a good idea.